# Issue saving QGraphicsScene to a PNG file

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qpainter, qimage

I have a `QGraphicScene` object that I can save to a PNG file just fine as long as I haven't made any modifications like a scroll or a zoom on the item.  After performing a scroll or a zoom, the saved image becomes small with a lot of transparent pixels filling in the desired dimensions.  I'm thinking it has to do with needing to render the visible region of the `QGraphicsView` to the `QImage` that gets saved but I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Below is some of my code:

```
void myClass::saveSceneAsPNGImage(QString path, int width)
{
    Scene->clearSelection();

    double scaleFactor = (width / Scene->sceneRect().size().width());

    QImage image(Scene->sceneRect().size().width() * scaleFactor, 
        Scene->sceneRect().size().height() * scaleFactor, 
        QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    QPainter painter(&image);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    Scene->render(&painter);
    image.save(path);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what result you would like to have at the end?

Comment: I'd like to have the scene that I can see in my GUI (the way it's scrolled and zoomed) saved to a PNG file with dimensions that may vary from the original size of the scene.

Comment: Maybe you can upload the two pictures, with and without zoom.